# Bash one liner to clean out junk files from NAS

Tags: networking, bash, nas

I bought a [2-bay QNAP NAS](http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_feature.asp?p_id=178) that I'll put 2 x 2TB hard drives in today and load up with my files. I'll be accessing the NAS via Xubuntu/Debian and Mac machines.

I'd like someone to teach me a bash one-liner (or something similar) that will clear out some of the junk files that have accumulated over the years of multi-platform access.

These include things like:

- `.ini`
- `thumbs.db`
- `.AppleDouble`
- `.DS_Store`
- `:2e*`

I don't want to delete *crucial* metadata files, but `.ini` for example, I don't view as crucial and the same goes for `.DS_Store`.

Additionally, are there any easy ways to be proactive in the fight against spreading these junk files around? On the Mac, I did:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

a while back which should take care of future .DS_Store network spam. I'm not completely OCD but I'd like to avoid useless files where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find path/to/nas \( -name '.ini' -o -name ':2e*' -o ... \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm looking forward to doing some weeding!